# React-Redux- Not Getting output

Tags: reactjs, redux

First time i am trying redux , i am not getting output.
Can any one help me out.

Component

```
import * as storyboardActions from '../actions/storyboardActions';
handleClickHello() {
    this.props.storyboardActions.testAction();
}

<div>
    <h4>This is the dashboard</h4>
    <a onClick={this.handleClickHello.bind(this)}>Knock Knock</a>
</div>
```

action

```
const API_URL = 'http://localhost:3000/api';  
export function testAction() {
    return function (dispatch) {
        axios.get(`$(API_URL)/helloworld`) .
            then(response => {
                dispatch({
                    type: types.TEST_ACTION,
                    payload: response.data,
                });
                console.log(response.data);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    };
}
```

Reducer

```
export default function (state = initialState.storyboard, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
    case types.ADD_NEW_STORYBOARD: {
        const board = {
            id: uuid(),
            boardTitle: 'A',
        };
        return [...state, board]
    }

    case types.TEST_ACTION:
    {
        return { ...state, message: action.payload.message };
    }
    default:
        return state;
    }
}
```

Inital state

```
export default {
    storyboard: [{
        id: '1fef',
        boardTitle: 'B1',
        message: ''
    }],
};
```

trying to get the output hello word but i am not able to see that.

Is This a right way what i am approaching??

Comment: I don't understand, in your component, you don't try to render anything from the state. What does your console.logs prints?

Comment: A problem I detected is that your `initialState.storyboard` is an array while on your reducer you convert it to an object.

Comment: @GershonPapi sorry can you please elobrate

Comment: storyboard: [{id: '1fef', boardTitle: 'B1'},{message: '' }] You mean to say this

Comment: Else how to resolve that?? can you please guide me

Comment: Please post the code for your component as well. Its important to see how you're connecting to redux

Comment: @JoshuaUnderwood  i have update..i cannot paste full code here it is too long

Answer (score 0):

Just change the state to:

```
storyboard: {
    id: '1fef',
    boardTitle: 'B1',
    message: ''
}
```

And change also in `case types.ADD_NEW_STORYBOARD` the following:

```
return {...state, id: uuid(), boardTitle: 'A'};
```

Comment: That didn't work, I am working for case types.TEST_ACTION: